# electronic scheme "R1=2500M" how many ohm?

Tags: resistors

I have an electonic scheme of a Sony microphone that indicate R1 as 2500M. But how many ohm is "2500M" ?

thanks a lot[image]

Comment: Looks like 2.5GOhm, which is pretty high.

Comment: Yeah. It suggests that they use a very good assembly line.

Answer (score 2):

Just as it says. 2500 megohm or 2.5 Gohm.

This is a fairly normal value in a professional capacitor microphone.

The capsule will be a capacitor of around 15-30pF; sound waves in air move one of the plates to change its value.

Work out what resistance you need to make an R-C high pass filter with C=30pF and a flat response to 20Hz.

(EDIT : C101 surprises me. If it's a 10dB pad to increase max SPL before overload, I could understand that, but I would have expected it to be switchable for greater sensitivity)